# Invoke command on output of awk

Tags: unix, awk

I am a beginner of shell scripting and I need to run a command where I get the first columns from a file (based on the separator ~). The output of that command lists all the names in new line, which I then need to convert to a comma separated list. Below is the command:

```
FILES=`cat 'testfile.txt' | grep 'teststring' | 
       awk -F~ '{print $1}'| sed 's/\n/\,/g' | awk '{print;}'`
```

Running this prints the contents of the file in new line, but I don't get the comma separated final o/p. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You don't need to `cat` files into `grep`, you can just use `grep "pattern" file`. You don't need `grep` before `awk` either, since `awk` can search for patterns just as well as `grep` if you do `awk '/pattern/{code}' file`.

Comment: can you please post what the command will be?

Comment: Edit your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
FILES=`awk -v RS='~' -v ORS=, '/teststring/' 'testfile.txt' `
```

- we use `~` as a record separator, which splits the input at `~` into different *lines*
- we use the `/teststring/` instead of grep
- the `{print $0}` can be ommitted (`$0` is the *line*, we get from splitting at `~`)  as it is the default action
- by setting the `ORS` (output record separator) to `,` we get the comma separated output

Comment: how do I get the comma separated list from the above?

Comment: @user1318369 By setting ORS. I changed my answer.

Comment: The txt file has 4 columns and I only need the first one. Running this gives all the columns as a comma separated list. How do I only get the first column?

Comment: @user1318369 Please update your question to show same example input lines with their expected output.

Comment: @user1318369 I dont know if I understand you correctly but `awk -v FS='~' -v ORS=, '/teststring/ {print $1}'` might work.

Answer (score 0):

`paste` is a good tool to convert newlines to commas:

```
files=$(awk -F~ '/teststring/ {print $1}' testfile.txt | paste -s -d,)
```

Don't use ALLCAPSVARNAMES, it's too easy to trample shell variables and break your script